# How to remove any contact from google talk (gtalk)?

Tags: google-talk, google-contacts, gmail-contacts

I want to remove some contacts from my gtalk list. For that purpose I have done:

1. removed those contacts from gmail contact
2. removed relevant emails of those contacts

but still, they do not removed from gtalk list and appear there. When I move cursor to their contact it only show 4 options as **Block**  , **Never Show**, **Always Show** and **Auto**.  There is not such option to remove it. Also I found this [link](https://support.google.com/talk/answer/23940?hl=en) but no help. It says to right click and remove, but I didn't find any right place to right click.

Is there any way, resource/link from where I can know a good way to achieve this ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you removed them from your Google+ circles too?

Comment: Thanks @KaranRajBaruah I just did that.. and it worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I removed them from all of my gmail context, I also have to remove them from **Google+** circle (if added into any). I removed those contacts from **Google+** Circle as well. After I edited my circle, it asked me to remove contact on yellow bar, after click on this finally that contact removed.!! and it worked..!! :)  I dont know why above google link did not mentioned this.